# Check and uncheck all checkboxes by clicking an image using jquery

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I am trying to check or uncheck all checkboxes when a user clicks a "check"image using jquery. I can get it to work if I have an input type="checkbox" but if I use an image it does not work.

HTML:

```
<th align="center"><img src="images/checkbox.gif" id="checkAll" name="checkAll"/></th>
```

jQuery:

```
     $('#checkAll').click(function(event) { //on click
        if(this.checked) { // check select status
            $('.chkaction').each(function() { //loop through each checkbox
                this.checked = true;                
            });
        }else{
            $('.chkaction').each(function() { //loop through each checkbox
                this.checked = false; 
            });        
        }
    });
```

Comment: You mean when the checkboxes are images? Or when you click on an image?

Comment: Well, an image does not have a checked state `this.checked` would not work

Comment: There is an check image in the header of the column. I want to click that image and all the checkboxes in the column below the header need to be checked. If I click it again then they need to uncheck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just keep the state in jQuery's `data()`, as an image can't be checked/unchecked

```
$('#checkAll').on('click', function () {
    var checked = !$(this).data('checked');

    $('.chkaction').prop('checked', checked);

    $(this).data('checked', checked);
});
```

Iterating over the checkboxes with `each()` is not neccessary, jQuery's `prop()` can be used instead.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ujx52/)

Comment: The only problem with this is if the OP changes the state of each checkbox manually. In your fiddle, if you check them all initially, nothing will happen the first time you click it. I think the following behavior is better http://jsfiddle.net/Ujx52/1/

Comment: This worked. I am able to check all and uncheck all by clicking the image.

Comment: @mac3201 But if you follow the steps I showed in my comment, you'll see it doesn't work in that case

Comment: @JuanMendes - This is how it usually works, noone really bothers to check if all the boxes are checked like that, but it's a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, what happens in this case is the following.

- If all boxes are checked, you uncheck them.
- If any box is not checked, you check them.

Because if you just toggle all, the behavior is hard to follow after you manually change each checkbox.

http://jsfiddle.net/Ujx52/1/

```
$('#checkAll').on('click', function () {
    var allChecked = true;
    $('.chkaction').each(function(){
        if (!this.checked) {
            allChecked = false;
        }
    });
    $('.chkaction').prop('checked', !allChecked);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I am adding/removing a class on the image for the status of the checkboxes.

```
$('#checkAll').click(function(event) { //on click
    var self = $(this);
    if( !self.hasClass('check') ) { // check select status
        self.addClass('check');
        $('.chkaction').each(function() { //loop through each checkbox
            this.checked = true;                
        });
    } else {
        self.removeClass('check');
        $('.chkaction').each(function() { //loop through each checkbox
            this.checked = false; 
        });        
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Place  tage in  tag. And write code for click event.

```
<a href='#'><img src="images/checkbox.gif" id="checkAll" name="checkAll"/><a>
```